# what is the purpose of overlay network driver?

Tags: linux, docker, lxc, cluster

Below is the command run on ubuntu  to create `overlay` network driver for swarm cluster instead of using `bridge` network driver

```
     $ docker network create -d overlay xyz


$ docker network ls                      
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER        SCOPE
9c431bc9fec7        bridge              bridge        local
88a4c6a29fa4        docker_gwbridge     bridge        local
10a4bc649237        host                host          local
o79qllmq86xw        ingress             overlay       swarm
417aca5efd6b        none                null          local
nsteeoxfu9b1        xyz                 overlay       swarm
$
```

---

```
$ docker service create --name service_name --network xyz -p 80:80 --repicas 12 <image>
```

What exactly is the purpose of service command using option `--network xyz`?

**edit**

Is this something related to.... how network namespace works? Mentioned here...

https://youtu.be/kl8roLaLy-g

And

https://youtu.be/_WgUwUf1d34

If yes, Is each network namespace a dedicated(separate) TCP-IP-ethernetLayer stack on same host?

Comment: @Haxiel query edited...

Answer (score 2):

Docker uses different types of network drivers to implement the communication between containers and external networks. The default network driver is the `bridge` driver. With this driver, a software bridge allows containers connected to the same bridge to talk to each other. Containers connected to different bridges are isolated from each other. The bridge driver is also scoped to a single host, so containers situated on different hosts cannot talk to each other.

When using Docker Swarm, you typically have a multi-host setup with docker daemons running on each host. To facilitate communication is this scenario, you need the `overlay` driver. Each docker daemon uses a `bridge` network (named 'docker_gwbridge'), and the `overlay` network sits on top (overlays) of these host-specific networks. The `overlay` driver can then allow communication between different Docker daemons, facilitating swarm functionality.

For more details, see the [Docker documentation on networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/).

The two specific commands in the question create and then use a new `overlay` network. The [docker network create](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/) commands creates your new `overlay` network. The [docker service create](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/) command defines the new service, and specifies that it is attached to the previously created `overlay` network.

Comment: So... 1) Is `docker_gwbridge` a layer2 connectivity between the different network namespaces in same host 2) Is `overlay` a layer3 connectivity  between docker daemons of multiple hosts?

Comment: I'm a bit out of my depth here, so I'll refer you to this in-depth article about the Docker networking implementation : [link](https://success.docker.com/article/networking). Typically, each container has a network namespace so that it has an isolated network stack. From there, the Docker networks allow communication. The networks are built using different technologies, such as a Linux bridge for the `bridge` driver and a VXLAN data plane for the `overlay` driver.

Comment: After doing some experiments with docker... I see that, `docker0` end point gets created in addition to physical and loopback interface, after installing of `docker-ce`. `ip link` & `docker network ls` confirms that. When I enable swarm mode, then I get these extra two points... `docker_gwbridge` & `veth49d700f@if24`. Read the design spec from here..https://github.com/docker/libnetwork/blob/master/docs/design.md